# Load view template on module activation

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have developed a blogger-like archive feature (you know, from the feature module).
I want to edit the .module file in order to automatically load the view-template (which is bundled in the feature) into the theme. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "automatically load the view-template into the theme"? Tnx!

Comment: i actually meant two things, sorry.
first, i want the tpl.php to be actually available for the feature to use it (just as if it were in the active theme folder).
secondly, when you create a view--something.tpl.php it needs to be loaded (rescan on views_ui). i'd like it to be automatically loaded.

Comment: http://grayside.org/2010/09/how-override-views-field-template-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general level: you should think "**features = modules**" and leaving theming for... themes! This does not mean that you shouldn't include a template with your feature, but that you should **evaluate whether the template you have built suits a general use of your feature or it is specific for your currently used theme**. If it is the latter case, you should not package your template file with the feature, but leave it with the theme instead. Just think to how the *views module* works, to get an idea of what I mean.

[Maybe you are already aware of this and made your considerations to this regards, in which case simply disregard what above. I thought about writing it because your sentence *"I want the tpl.php to be actually available for the feature to use it (just as if it were in the active theme folder)"* surprised me as general-use templates do not live in the theme folder but in the their module one, and moreover views already provide a "general use" template.]

That said, the way you normally tell drupal to use a given template, is via implementing [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme/6) in your module. In this case - though - given that you are going to override the template defined by views you should implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6) instead.

Somebody actually [already did it](http://drupal.org/node/645716). Here's the code snippet from the linked page:

```
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $my_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
  $hooks = array('node');  // you can do this to any number of template theme hooks
  // insert our module
  foreach ($hooks as $h) {
    _MYMODULE_insert_after_first_element($theme_registry[$h]['theme paths'], $my_path);
  }
}

function _MYMODULE_insert_after_first_element(&$a, $element) {
  $first_element = array_shift($a);
  array_unshift($a, $first_element, $element);
}
```

Of course you will have to alter the theme registry for your view, rather than for a node (the original example refers to a CCK type).

As on using the template in the views_ui, I am not sure weather the features module already empty the theming cache when you install a feature (in which case you should be good to go). If not, you can trigger it manually by invoking [cache_clear_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/cache_clear_all/6) from your install file. If emptying the entire cache is too much, you should dig into the views module on how to flush the cache relatively to a single views.

Hope this helps!

Comment: features module does empty the theme cache, indeed.
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your feature .module file

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['theme paths']['views'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
}
```

On the .install file use this

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_enable().
 */
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  drupal_rebuild_theme_registry();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my snippet to declare views templates stored in the "template" folder of my "custom_module":

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function custom_module_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $extension   = '.tpl.php';
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module');
  $files       = file_scan_directory($module_path . '/templates', '/' . preg_quote($extension) . '$/');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $template = drupal_basename($file->filename, $extension);
    $theme    = str_replace('-', '_', $template);
    list($base_theme, $specific) = explode('__', $theme, 2);

    // Don't override base theme.
    if (!empty($specific) && isset($theme_registry[$base_theme])) {
      $theme_info = array(
        'template'   => $template,
        'path'       => drupal_dirname($file->uri),
        'variables'  => $theme_registry[$base_theme]['variables'],
        'base hook'  => $base_theme,
        // Other available value: theme_engine.
        'type'       => 'module',
        'theme path' => $module_path,
      );

      $theme_registry[$theme] = $theme_info;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.