# hook_preprocess_page() does not seem to use the suggested template file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am suggesting a template file in the `hook_preprocess_page()` implementation done from a module, but the suggested template file doesn't seem to be used.

The template file is page--terminal-template.tpl.php, which is in the directory containing the module, and this is the implementation of `hook_preprocess_page()`.

```
function terminal_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == "terminal") {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__terminal_template";
  }
}
```

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this hook can also be called from theme's template.php file along with module's hook.

Please refer Drupal 7 documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).

Say if your active theme is MY_THEME, then the code should be:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == "terminal") {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = "page__terminal_template";

  }
}
```

And the template suggestions will work.

Edit: This functionality can also be implemented with Modules using hooks.

Comment: my theme name was journalcrunch.so i used journalcrunch__preprocess_page(&$variables) { in the template.php file still the function is called but not the theme

Comment: Correct the function name to  journalcrunch_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

Comment: sorry for the mistake.I wrote the function name as journalcrunch_preprocess_page(&$variables) .somehow entered an extra underscore while commenting.I cleared the cache ..and still not working

Comment: It is wrong: Preprocess and process functions can be implemented by modules too. See the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7). Notice there is [shortcut_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21shortcut%21shortcut.module/function/shortcut_preprocess_page/7), which is implemented by a module.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess and process functions can be implemented by modules. In fact, the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) lists them when it shows in which order those functions are called.

The fact is that Drupal looks for the suggested template files in the theme directory. You have these alternatives:

1. Put the template files your module is suggesting in the directory containing the theme currently used
2. Follow what reported in [Load view template on module activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835457/drupal-load-view-template-on-module-activation) to load the template files from the module directory
3. Suggest the template files you want to use in a preprocess function implemented by a theme

Following what reported in the other question, you would be able to use the template file found in the module directory. The only *problem* is that you would be using a generic template that could be different from the default page template used from the currently enabled theme.

If you are adding template files for the currently enabled theme, you should call [drupal_theme_rebuild()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_rebuild/7) to make Drupal rescan the directory containing the template files, after you added the new template file to the theme.