# How to create custom template file for login/register pages of profile2 each user role in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm making a job vacancies site and it has two roles, user and employer. I used `profile2` and have unique registration path for both roles. I already make the custom `login/register` page for user and it goes well.
**I want to make custom `login/register` page for employer too.**
I already tried making `page--employer.tpl.php` and it didn't work.

Here is codes in `page--user.tpl.php` for user `login/register`:

```
<?php if(!user_is_logged_in()): ?>
<div class="vertical-align user-page-form">
<div class="vertical-align-center">
<div class="horizontal-align-middle">
  <div id="up-logo">
    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" rel="home">
      <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <?php if ($messages): ?>
    <?php print $messages; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>

  <div class="login-footer">
  <?php if($_GET['q'] == 'user' || $_GET['q'] == 'user/login'): ?>
    <?php print l('Create new account', 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'left'))); ?>
    <?php print l('Reset your password', 'user/password', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'right'))); ?>
  <?php elseif($_GET['q'] == 'user/register'): ?>
    <?php print l('Sign in', 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'left'))); ?>
    <?php print l('Reset your password', 'user/password', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'right'))); ?>
  <?php elseif($_GET['q'] == 'user/password'): ?>
    <?php print l('Create new account', 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'left'))); ?>
    <?php print l('Sign in', 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'right'))); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php else: ?>

  <div class="page">
  <?php if ($tabs): ?>
  <div class="tabs"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement (in your template.php) `template_preprocess_page($variables)` and add your own template file name suggestion via the `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` array.

You can check the current path (in an if statement to know when to add the suggestion) with [current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7.x) or [drupal_get_path_alias()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7.x)

Take a look at the API for [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x).

Also take a look at [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625218/hook-preprocess-page-does-not-seem-to-use-the-suggested-template-file)